# Singular Value Decomposition - Understanding the geometric visualisation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, svd

[image]

The Singular Value Decomposition of a matrix A satisfies $\mathbf A = \mathbf U \mathbf \Sigma \mathbf V^\top$.

I wanted to clarify how this diagram works. I understand this diagram if the "inputs" into $A$ are two orthogonal basis vectors, but how come the outputs are also orthogonal? How would you know this would be true for *any* rectangular matrices?

Or is it more so saying "If we know the image of two vectors we can define the linear map by matrix $A$, and we choose two special vectors such that their images will be $\sigma_1 u_1$ and $ \sigma_2 u_2 $? But then how would you know that these two special vectors will be orthogonal? (So that ( V^T ) makes sense?)

Thanks,

Comment: $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}^{\perp}$ are unitary, or rotation matrices, so they preserve the angles between the vectors. So, first, the eigenvectors $v_1, v_2$ of $\mathbf{V}$ (they're orthogonal) are mapped into two orthogonal basis vectors $e_1, e_2$, then scaled by  $\Sigma$ into orthogonal $\sigma_1e_1, \sigma_2e_2$, then mapped by unitary $\mathbf{U}$ to $\sigma_1u_1, \sigma_2u_2$. The linear map $A$ is fully defined by the transformation of these vectors since every vector can be decomposed by the basis of $\mathbf{V}$, and we know the linear map rules for the basis vectors

Comment: @diplodoc Thanks for your reply! I'm just wondering, wouldn't this mean all linear maps $ A $ map perpendicular vectors to perpendicular vectors? That's not generally true, right?
Also could you please explain why $v_1$ and $v_2$ are eigenvectors of $V$? I didn't quite understand how a rotation would have eigenvectors?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. $v_1, v_2$ are columns of $\mathbf{V}$, so they're orthogonal, since $\mathbf{V}$ is unitary (same for $u_1, u_2$). Moreover, by definition $v_1, v_2$ are eigenvectors of $A^*A$ and $u_1, u_2$ are eigenvectors of $AA^*$.
As for the first question, if $\sigma_1 \neq \sigma_2$, then the only perpenducular vectors having perpendicular images, are $v_1, v_2$

Comment: @diplodoc Thanks again, I'm not quite sure however if I grasped. Can you please confirm if my understanding below is correct?:
- First we take two vectors in the im(A) which will be perpendicular (Assuming A is non-singular for the purpose of visualisation)
- Find the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ which map to those perpendicular vectors (I'm not quite sure why $v_1$ and $v_2$ need to be orthonormal if this is how we defined them?)
- Make $v_1$ and $v_2$ the columns of $\mathbf{V}$?

Comment: First, we find the orthonormal eigenvectors of $A^*A$ and $AA^*$. (we can always find a set of perpendicular eigenvalues). These are $v_1, v_2$ and $u_1, u_2$ by definition. Next, we find the singular values $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ as the square roots of eigenvalues of either $AA^*$ or $A^*A$. If $a = \alpha_1v_1 + \alpha_2v_2$, then $Aa = \alpha_1\sigma_1v_1 + \alpha_2\sigma_2v_2$.
$v_1, v_2$ and $u_1, u_2$ are the columns of $\mathbf{V}, \mathbf{U}$ respectively
If you are curious about why $\sigma_1u_1, \sigma_2u_2$ are the images of $v_1, v_2$, you should look up the proof of SVD